# Workflow between blender and xcode (scenekit)

Tags: ios, blender, scenekit

Im using blender to create landscape for a game being built with scenekit.

As it is just a landscape, I won't be using any animations so I'm wondering before I dive too deep into blender, should I be using blender to create the geometry and then create my own materials in scenekit?

I could still create the shadow, emission, specular etc. maps in blender but would there be a performance benefit or penalty for doing it this way?

Also if this is a path I could take should I then be exporting as .dae or is there a way to export to a normal map that xcode would be happy with?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SceneKit supports materials exported in DAE from Blender. It doesn't support every possible shading option that Blender has, but unless you're doing exotic stuff it should cover most of what you're looking for.

At run time there's no difference between materials loaded from DAE and those created programmatically.

What you *do* want to think about at authoring/export time is stuff like real-time versus static lighting/shadows and high-poly geometry versus baked normal maps. In other words, material performance is more about *how* the materials are set up (complexity) than *where* they're set up (imported or at run time). See [WWDC 2014 session 610: Building a Game with SceneKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/) for some tips.

Comment: Awesome, I'll have to have a play with the overlap between the two and see what suits best. Expanding on using baked normal maps, would that be to add finer detail to a low poly geometry or using heightmap data as the source for custom geometry? If that's even possible with scenekit